# Is Schmähkritik illegal in Germany and what could happen?

Tags: germany, freedom-of-speech

[Jan Böhmermann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_B%C3%B6hmermann) made a [Schmähkritik about the president of Turkey, Erdoğan](http://www.zeit.de/kultur/film/2016-04/recep-tayyip-erdogan-gedicht-zdf-jan-boehmermann). Is that illegal, what could happen? Could Erdoğan actually sue ZDF and the satirist? What would happen, if he would do that?

And how/where should he sue him? He lives in Turkey and it's a German satire show.

Comment: http://www.faz.net/aktuell/feuilleton/medien/ermittlungen-gegen-jan-boehmermann-wegen-erdogan-gedicht-14163940.html

Comment: Related/follow-up question: http://law.stackexchange.com/q/8471/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the links in the article you quoted, you find that it is indeed illegal in Germany to insult a foreign head of state. For a prosecution to happen, the foreign government has to ask for prosecution, and it would be a criminal case. It's not clear to me whether a TV station could be sued as well.

Where Mr. Böhmermann lives would be irrelevant, what would be relevant is whether the insult happened in Germany.