# Why may the German government decide if Jan Böhmermann will be prosecuted?

Tags: germany, slander

[According to the German *ZEIT ONLINE* article *Bundesregierung prüft Strafbegehren der Türkei*](http://www.zeit.de/kultur/film/2016-04/jan-boehmermann-strafverfolgung-bundesregierung-pruefung), Turkey requested that Germany prosecutes the German citizen [Jan Böhmermann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_B%C3%B6hmermann) over a poem, and now German politicians in the *Bundesregierung* intend to decide if Böhmermann should be prosecuted.

I don't get it. I thought Germany has a [separaton of powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_powers)?

Comment: "Over a poem" - that is very strongly misleading.

Comment: @gnasher729: But it’s accurate, isn’t it? (I added it; in line with the title of *The Guardian* article [*Turkey asks Germany to prosecute comedian **over Erdoğan poem***](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/apr/11/turkey-germany-prosecute-comedian-jan-bohmermann-erdogan-poem).) As far as I understand it, this question is not *about* this specific case, but about why the Bundesregierung can (with separation of powers in mind) have a say in this and similar cases. -- But if you think this needs clarification, feel free to [edit] it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *Bundesregierung* is (like the police, the prosecuting authority, etc.) part of Germany’s executive.

[StGB § 104a](http://dejure.org/gesetze/StGB/104a.html) defines under which conditions offences described in chapter 3 *Straftaten gegen ausländische Staaten* (transl. *Offences against foreign states*), which consists of [§ 102](http://dejure.org/gesetze/StGB/102.html), [§ 103](http://dejure.org/gesetze/StGB/103.html) and [§ 104](http://dejure.org/gesetze/StGB/104.html), can be prosecuted.

One of the conditions is

> […] und die Bundesregierung die Ermächtigung zur Strafverfolgung erteilt

= the *Bundesregierung* must authorise the prosecution.

Comment: Just an explanation why this makes sense: The guy is apparently not prosecuted for a poem, but for speech insulting a foreign head of state. That's a very special case. It's about relationships between countries. If a German citizen insults say any random American citizen, that's between the two of them. If you insult the US president, it's a matter between the countries, not a private matter anymore. So if the US president complained, it would be the German government deciding whether the case should be heard. It's about the relationship of the countries, so no business for a judge alone.

Comment: @gnasher729 I agree, but still a somewhat draconian law, IMO. (Not that "MO" matters anyway, but just saying.)