# Charges I may face for limerick

Tags: united-kingdom, scotland

I wrote a poem laughing at Recep Tayyip Erdogan as part of a contest for the Spectator magazine. Only when they published the winner I realised someone in Germany is being prosecuted for doing the same.

What charges am I facing? I live in Scotland.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jan Böhmermann faces prosecution in Germany for violating their penal code section 103 as discussed [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/14010/under-which-german-laws-is-it-illegal-to-mock-foreign-rulers). [Lèse-majesté](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A8se-majest%C3%A9) is not a crime in the UK, though apparently it was a common law crime in Scotland until 2010 (though not prosecuted since 1715). Though there is always the possibility of a defamation lawsuit, depending on what you say.

Comment: This is fine if he stays in Scotland. As you say, it is a crime in Germany and (possibly) Turkey. If he travels to those countries he could be charged.

Comment: It would also depend on what exactly was said.